# Query selector from nodelist

Tags: javascript

Query selector from nodelist

What would be the best way to do that, can be more efficient?

Thanks in advance

```js
function querySelectorFrom(selector, elements){
  var all = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  var temp = [];
  for(var i =0; i< elements.length;i++){
    if(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(all,elements[i])!==-1){
    temp.push(elements[i]);
    }
  }
  return temp;
}

var nodelist = document.querySelectorAll('div');

console.log(querySelectorFrom('.type1',nodelist));

/* 
<div class="type1">1</div>
<div class="type1">1</div>
*/
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="type1">1</div>
  <div class="type1">1</div>
  <div class="type2">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This question is mime or whatever, code just a tool, and it can be many way to solve the problem, if you can have better ideas can improve it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

In recent browsers, you can use [**`Element#matches`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) to filter the elements without having to select them all over again:

```
function querySelectorFrom(selector, elements) {
    return [].filter.call(elements, function(element) {
        return element.matches(selector);
    });
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function querySelectorFrom(selector, elements) {
    return [].filter.call(elements, function(element) {
        return element.matches(selector);
    });
}

var nodelist = document.querySelectorAll('div');

console.log(querySelectorFrom('.type1', nodelist));
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="type1">1</div>
  <div class="type1">1</div>
  <div class="type2">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, 'Element.matches' should be more faster than 'Array.indexOf'

Answer (score 0):

```js
function querySelectorFrom(selector, elements){
  var all = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  var temp = [];
  all.forEach(item => {
    console.log("item", item);
    if(temp.indexOf(item) === -1){
      temp.push(item);
    }
  });
   
  console.log("all", all);

}

var nodelist = document.querySelectorAll('div');

console.log(querySelectorFrom('.type1',nodelist));
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="type1">1</div>
  <div class="type1">1</div>
  <div class="type2">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over NodeLists directly in modern browsers with `forEach`. But, it would probably be even nicer to just convert both to arrays and then just use the proper array method, `.filter`, which filters its elements into another array based on a test:

```js
const querySelectorFrom = (selector, elements) => {
  const elementsArr = [...elements];
  return [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)]
    .filter(elm => elementsArr.includes(elm));
};
const nodelist = document.querySelectorAll('div');
console.log(querySelectorFrom('.type1',nodelist));
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="type1">1</div>
  <div class="type1">1</div>
  <div class="type2">2</div>
</div>
```